# Cargar registro de base de datos usando ef en asp core

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, entity-framework

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos en ASP.NET Core y se me hace un poco complicado y por tal motivo acudo a ustedes que siempre me han ayudado, anteriormente en C# implementaba el siguiente código para obtener el último registro de una base y visualizar sumando uno más para el registro de uno nuevo.

```
 public void ID_Paciente(TextBox txtCodigo)
    {
        try
        {
            string sql = @"SELECT ISNULL(MAX(PAC_CODIGO), 0) + 1 FROM TBL_PACIENTE";
            String connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trabajo"].ToString();
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstring))
            {
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
                conn.Open();
                string codmax = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());
                string cod = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar()).ToString("00000");
                txtCodigo.Text = Convert.ToString(cod);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ERROR : " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

La pregunta es como puedo plasmar este mismo código en ASP.NET Core MVC, hago uso de Entity Framework? y debería ir en el método on get para que se cargue a lo que abro la página.

De antemano agradezco su ayuda con una guía.

Comment: Dime si te resulto util la respuesta, gracias

Comment: Claro me sirvió, ahora solo me falta el poder leerlo desde la pagina el código que debería salir como secuencial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener el último registro insertado prueba este código:

```
var ultimoPaciente = tbl_Paciente.LastOrDefault();
int ultimoId = 0;

if(ultimoPaciente != null)
{
   ultimoId = ultimoPaciente.PAC_CODIGO;
}
```

Lo que se hace aquí es obtener el último paciente a través del **método** **LastOrDefault**, una vez obtenido el último paciente, preguntamos si no es **null**, de no ser **null** obtenemos el código del paciente, caso contrario se queda con el valor **0**, que fue el valor con que se inicializó la **variable ultimoId**.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```